# ata1: failed to read log page 10h (errno=-5). Is it a hardrive failure? If yes is it repairable( physical or using software)?

Tags: boot, hard-drive, data-recovery, raid, sata

So,i was trying to copy a huge load of data of my external hdd to my laptop's internal hdd using debian based distro. Suddenly my screen went all black. I waited for some time, pressed random keys(esc, enter etc.). Then forced shutdown my laptop using power button. When i powered it on, this happened. I tried using emergency, safe mode to no avail. No i am thinking if a fresh installation of OS is enough or i need to buy new HDD?
Parrot OS 4.7 
linux kernal 5.4

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: More than likely you just corrupted your hard disk. Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and show me a screenshot of `gparted`, and `sudo fdisk -l` (that's a lower case L). We'll try `fsck` next...

Answer (score 0):

I used an external casing and ran crystaldiskinfo S.M.A.R.T. It showed my disk in red and the reason was my disk ran out of reallocatable sectors. Sorry, Didn't take any screenshots.The disk had total time running of 4k+ hours. Should have known about S.M.A.R.T before. Drilled my HDD in rage!

Solution: none. The disk is recoverable though if you can spend (software or service). 
Also, you can use a live usb and run smart tools instead of searching for a enclosure.q